# why a renamed function doesn't work like the original function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, formula

I'm renaming a BASE R function called `factanal` to `efa` using `match.call`. But I'm wondering why ONLY when using a formula for argument `x`, `efa` throws in an error that: `object 'n.obs' not found` but `factanal` works fine?

**Note:** when using a `data.frame` for `x`, `efa` works fine.

```
efa <- function(x, factors, data = NULL, covmat = NULL, n.obs = NA,
            subset, na.action, start = NULL, center = FALSE,
            scores = c("none", "regression", "Bartlett"),
            rotation = "varimax", control = NULL, ...)
 {

 fit <- factanal(x, factors, data = data, covmat, n.obs = n.obs,
              subset, na.action, start = start,
              scores = scores,
              rotation = rotation, control = control, ...)

 fit$call <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

 return(fit)
}

# Example of use:

v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6)

factanal(~v1+v2+v3, factors = 1, data = data.frame(v1, v2, v3)) # Works fine
     efa(~v1+v2+v3, factors = 1, data = data.frame(v1, v2, v3)) # Error: object 'n.obs' not found

     efa(data.frame(v1, v2, v3), factors = 1) # Works fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more common way of doing this is to capture the call first, wrap out any parameter, then evaluate it. Something like this

```
efa <- function(x, factors, data = NULL, covmat = NULL, n.obs = NA,
                subset, na.action, start = NULL, center = FALSE,
                scores = c("none", "regression", "Bartlett"),
                rotation = "varimax", control = NULL, ...)
{

  cc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  cc[[1]] <- quote(factanal)
  fit <- eval.parent(cc)
  fit$call <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

  return(fit)
}
```

We can test with

```
efa(~v1+v2+v3, factors = 1, data = data.frame(v1, v2, v3))
# Call:
# efa(x = ~v1 + v2 + v3, factors = 1, data = data.frame(v1, v2,     v3))
# 
# Uniquenesses:
#    v1    v2    v3 
# 0.005 0.114 0.739 
# 
# Loadings:
#    Factor1
# v1 0.998  
# v2 0.941  
# v3 0.511  
# 
#                Factor1
# SS loadings      2.143
# Proportion Var   0.714
# 
# The degrees of freedom for the model is 0 and the fit was 0.0609
```

The reason this doesn't work otherwise with this function is that when you pass a value to `n.obs`, it assumes that's the name of the variable in your data.frame that contains the value you wish to use, it does not assume that's a variable in your current environment.

Comment: @joran. Right, it's related to `model.frame`.  If you have `dd <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5, n=1:5); model.frame(y~x, dd, n.obs=n)` it will add in a `(n.obs)` column to your output. And yes, it is also related to lazy evaluation because it grabs the variable name, not the current variable value. So it has more to do with the `...` om the `model.frame` function. Maybe I just didn't explain it well.

Comment: @joran. Part of what helps here is using `match.call` so if you didn't initially pass in the parameter, it wouldn't also be passed on to `model.frame`. So with the `subset=` that would allow things like `subset=x>3` or whatever but that's a special parameter to `model.frame` and not handled thought the `...`

Comment: @joran Another point being that despite the fact that NA is the default value for `n.obs`, passing that value triggers an error as well. `factanal(~v1+v2+v3, factors = 1, data = data.frame(v1, v2, v3), n.obs=NA)`. It really has to not be passed at all in this case.